# JavaFX loading images from CSS in Webstart

Tags: java, css, applet, javafx, java-web-start

I currently have a major problem with loading of CSS and images in JavaFX.

The goal is to make JavaFX load the images that are defined in the CSS file. I get this to work easily in the IDE and in the standalone execution. But once I try the the application as a applet and run it inside a browser context everything fails.

The CSS file is still load properly, but the image files remain blank. Sadly I can't find a way to make JavaFX log why the image loading is failing. All the images are located in subdirectories from the location of the CSS file and are accessed for example like this:

```
.button-gray {
    -fx-border-image-source: url("button/buttongray.png");
}
```

The CSS file is located in the same package as the class that handles loading it and is load like this:

```
final URL css = Util.class.getResource("sheet.css");
if (css != null) {
    parent.getStylesheets().add(css.toExternalForm());
}
```

I tried already placing the resources in the root directory and load it with `Util.class.getClassLoader.getResource(...)` and `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader.getResource(...)`. Both worked fine in case the application was executed as stand alone. Neither worked in case the application is launched from a webstart applet context.

But as I said. In all cases there is no indication that the CSS is not load. The styles defined in the stylesheet are applied properly with exception of the images.

I am running out of idea what the reason for this is. I package and publish the application using the gradle javafx plugin by shemnon.

Building environment:

- Oracle Java 1.7b45 x64
- Gradle 1.9

Anyone know how to fix this problem or has any idea how to debug it.
Sadly the logging facilities of JavaFX (even the CSS Logger) and the applet trace console give no indication what the problem is.

**New Information!**

The JNLP file is located here:
[JNLP-File](http://illarion.org/media/java/launcher/Illarion-Launcher.jnlp)

How ever, this file is not the problem. The problems seems to be the generation of the binary css file that is part of the deployment process of JavaFX for webstart. In this binary file, for some yet unknown reason there is a reference to the CSS file inside by building environment. This causes the CSS loader to load the image files from the location on my building server. Something that does not work in my local computer. Builds I did on my local computer on the other hand work because the files are still at the location its looking for.

So now the problem seems to be limited to the binary css generation that stores a entirely wrong file reference.

Comment: I may be stating the obvious, but just in case: you *have* verified that the JAR downloaded by WebStart *does* contain the images?

Comment: Its usually the obvious things that cause such problems. But not in this case. Yes I checked if the files are in the JAR and they are there. I even checked the file that is inside the WebStart cache.

Comment: Seems no one has a idea. Does anyone know about working examples of JavaFX webstart apps that load images from the CSS file?

Answer (score 0):

1) Can you post the .jnlp file that you're using to deploy the app? An incorrect .jnlp can cause resource loading issues like this.

2) Give us the exact invocation of Thread.currentThread().getContextCLassLoader.getResource("") that you're using.

3) Report the contents of the .jar file, with the *exact* folder/path structure of the file(s) in the jar that you need to load. For example, 'My code is looking for example.png, it should be in the pics.jar file inside the folder com/mycompany/myimages', something like that.

WebStart takes some doing to get working, but I'd suspect the answer lies in there somewhere.  If all else fails, I've found JaNeLa to be helpful in debugging web start deployment problems. http://pscode.org/janela/

Comment: JaNeLa fails once it comes to JavaFX jnlp files, as it does not support namespaces properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading the css file with:

```
final String css = getClass.getResource("sheet.css").toExternalForm();

parent.getStylesheets.add(css); // taken that parent is the name for the Scene.
```

For the css:

```
-fx-border-image-source: url("../button/buttongray.png");
```

Using URL and Util.class is not something that is common to use for loading stylesheets afaik.

Maybe try NetBeans IDE 7.4. Personally i don't know Gradle.

Comment: I tried the first one. And the second one fails in all cases because the file is not located there.

Comment: What if you tried it like in this turotial, using imageview. http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/button.htm. Not sure if css is the way to go for image use.

Comment: I edited my question adding the new information I found. The images work basically. But once the CSS is converted to the binary CSS, it all goes wrong.

Comment: Then you need to include the Base64 encoded url in the stylesheet, not the regular path. Maybe this article helps: http://mark.koli.ch/2009/07/howto-include-binary-image-data-in-cascading-style-sheets-css.html

Comment: The link you gave shows how to encode the image data as binary into the CSS file. This is not a possible solution in my case and does not resolve the actual problem with the wrong file path handling of the CSS to BSS conversation.

Comment: Refer to the css with its binary extension .BSS and not .CSS in your project.

Comment: If I do so, the effects as described in the question show up. The BSS file does NOT work. Only the CSS file does. The conversation CSS to BSS creates a corrupted BSS file.